# Asignarle una operación matemática que esta en un string a una variable C++

Tags: c++, string, operador

En este problema me están pasando un **string** con una operación matemática ((10+10)/(3-1)). me pregunto si existe alguna función en C++ o en una **biblioteca (librería)** que me permita hacer esta operación matemática y guardarla en una variable.

```
#include <iostream>

int main( ){

char *operador = "(10+10)/(3-1)";

    float a;
    // la funcion que necesito
    a= Funcioncalculo(*operador);

    std::cout << a << endl;
}
```

Comment: Tal vez te sirva: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329406/evaluating-arithmetic-expressions-from-string-in-c

Comment: por lo que e consultado la calculadora de linux **bc** hace lo que necesito, alguien tiene idea de como invocarla en mi código o usarla de alguna manera.

Comment: Si esto es con motivo de un ejercicio de clase tal vez lo que te están pidiendo es precisamente que implementes la lógica para resolver esa ecuación en vez de usar librerías de terceros

Answer (score 3):

La funcion que describes es un parser, que **no es soportado de forma nativa o estandar por c++**, te sugiero que busques en internet por librerias o implementaciones para resolver este problema, la mayoria de los casos lo que hacen es convertirlo a notacion polaca inversa (RPN) , y de ahi resolver el problema